# How to run .exe file of swing application over Local Area Network?

Tags: java, swing, deployment, lan

I have completed the development of my java swing desktop application and also make executable file of my application. It is working fine on single desktop but how should i run executable file over Local Area Network with multiple instances ?

Comment: Elaborate on the "run executable file over Local Area Network with multiple instances" part....

Comment: Why not make a web Application instead ?

Comment: Respected Sir/Mam, i want to implement in such a way that more than one user should be able to make entries into single database via different instances of executable file from different machines present in local area network.

Comment: Do you mean you have made it into an .exe? or a .jar? you need to let us know more about your application: does it access any databases? if so, have you included all required jars and libraries into the .exe (when you created the .exe from the jar) or the folder which houses the jar?

Comment: You need a shared database. Which database system do you use?

Comment: Respected Sir/Mam, yes you are right,i have created a .exe file of my application, it uses MySql database storage, my application deals with storing customer name and product delivered to him/her. Now how should i implement it in such a way that it should be accessed by 2 to 3 operators thus allowing them to make simultaneous entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is WebStart.  Instead of serving the Swing application as an EXE over the network, you'll instead create a WebStart deployment of the application to allow other users to access the application.

Comment: Respected Sir, Can you please share any link from where i will be able to learn the implementation and usage of WebStart ?

Comment: Start with the [Java Web Start info.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) here at SO.